# CSS dropdown menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I've made this dropdown menu, and I'm stuck on the jQuery part.

This is what I've got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/WuP9V

The script should slideDown the current `ul` attached to the `li`,
it works with pure css, but as you see I'm not able to move the mouse down to the sub menu.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just use a jquery plugin like superfish, don't reinvent the wheel. http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Comment: why would one use plugin for a such a simple task?

Comment: I guess it depends on how complex your menu is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The submenu is opening too far from the menu item, just adjust the "top" value of your `.bithackNavigationWrapper ul ul` class to something like 23px and it works fine.